# why an advanced LSTM model result is no better than the result from a simpler one?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have implemented the model proposed in [this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1167/) article which is a text classification model that uses sentence representation rather than only word representation to classify texts.

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
embeding_layer=layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size,self.word_vector_dim,weights=[word_embeding_matrix],trainable=False,mask_zero=False)
model.add(TimeDistributed(embeding_layer))
model.add(TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(costumized_lstm.Costumized_LSTM(50)))
model.add(layers.Dense(6,activation='softmax'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy',self.f1_m,self.precision_m, self.recall_m])
self.model=model
```

and I use a dataset with 40000 documents with 6 different labels to train it. (30000 for train and 10000 for the test). I uses a pretrained word embeding and the input for this model is (sample,sentences,words). it achieves 84% accuracy. the problem is that I can achieve this accuracy very easily with this simple model:

```
        model=tf.keras.Sequential()
    embeding_layer=layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size,self.word_vector_dim,weights=[word_embeding_matrix],trainable=False,mask_zero=False)
    model.add(embeding_layer)
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(50)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(6,activation='softmax'))
    opt=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy',self.f1_m,self.precision_m, self.recall_m])
    self.model=model
```

this one is not based on sentence representation and the input for this model is (sample, words).
what is wrong with the first model ? is my implementation wrong? what should I do?

the training process for both models overfits at 84%. I also have used every trick to overcome overfitting but I haven't got any results. any suggestions please?
[![enter image description here][2]][2]